# taxonomy auto-path views path issue

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have used the taxonomy menu and auto path to create a url alias something like below. The reason is so that the taxonomy menu has the right path.

/my-alias/[term:name]

I then enabled the taxonomy view and modified the view page so that it is like url below.This view grabs the taxonomy term and then filters that term and displays the fields in the view this works fine when I test it in the view itself

/my-alias/%

My question is how do I get drupal 7 to look at the view url first and not send it to the taxonomy alias?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you are using the same URL for both a view and a node - this is a really bad idea in most circumstances.

If you always want the view to show - what does it matter if the taxonomy itself is at /category/tag/[term:name]?

You might find Page Manager useful for what you're trying to do, there's a [fantastic free tutorial and familiarisation set of videos](https://drupalize.me/videos/overview-page-manager-series?p=1147) that have helped me immensely of late.

Comment: Issue I am having is creating a menu item for example /my-alias/water.  As there is no content called water

Comment: If there is no content, what are you hoping will happen?

Comment: It will display all of the taxonomy terms in that catergory

Comment: Another solution would be modify the taxonomy tpl so that it can display the fields I want

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, you haven't made any mention of categorising your terms in the question.  If all you want to do is show fields of taxonomy terms, what about `/admin/structure/taxonomy/[vocabulary:name]/display` ?

Comment: I think I might have the idea of taxonomy wrong. If I add a term to my list inside a taxonomy category and then press on that link, should it not display all the nodes that have that taxonomy term attached to it?

Comment: If by 'category' you mean vocabulary, yes, taxonomies are a way of classifying content.  From your question above it appeared you wanted to display fields that were attached to individual tags on the tag page which is possible, but not a very normal use-case.  In any case, if you have no content that is labelled 'water' then no content will display on the term page for water.

Comment: https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/9017/product-catalog-terms-and-nodes this is what I am looking for. Thanks for your help